# Why would an array of checkboxes sometimes not save?

Tags: php, forms, arrays, checkbox

Sometimes, when I submit a form that gathers checkbox data, the checkbox data displays perfectly and other times, the values don't display at all.  Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Any answer to this question will be speculation until you provide some code samples.

Comment: Maybe provide a little bit more information?

Comment: speculation is fine, is there a server issue that *could* cause this problem?  Multiple people have looked at this code without finding anything wrong with it

Comment: unchecked checkboxes won't appear in $_GET or $_POST data, their values aren't sent to the server

Comment: You don't mean that it doesn't show up when they're unchecked, do you? Checkbox form keys aren't sent if they're unchecked

Comment: I have a list of checkboxes for a survey type website.  The checkboxes are named answers[].  I get this array by doing $answers = $_POST['answers'] and do a foreach loop to list each value, sometimes the values appear when certain boxes are checked, and other times the same exact checked boxes don't display.

Comment: Jake is correct. You have to link their existence to `input` data. I recently did a dynamic multi-checkbox input that used javascript to insert `input` elements into a `form` space whenever they were clicked on or off.

Comment: No, I'm talking about only the checked ones.

Comment: Not if they're unchecked they don't

Comment: @Rob - you'll honestly get better responses if you could clarify your question and post some code.  So far all we've got is "Sometimes this happens".  There are dozens of reasons things could be going wrong, and you haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: @Rob Schneider - Actually, speculation is fine when it's not *the only* response possible.  Those of us with the right reputation can vote to close questions like this, provided we give a reason.  And one of the reasons to choose from is this: "*Not a real question* It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." Which I am tempted to enact upon this one.

Answer (score 1):

1. A typo in your code
2. You misunderstand how checkboxes work
3. Ineffective debugging logic
4. Bad logic to begin with

Those would be the most likely causes. If you share some code and a more specific example I bet it can be narrowed down even further.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a problem with your URL structure. You may be trying to post data to a URL thats different then your current location. This tends to look like a cross site scripting attack and the server won't be able to grab your posted variables in this case.

**Example of what I'm talking about:**

I have a form here: http://www.mywebsite.com/myform.php

Now I try to submit the form to: http://mywebsite.com/myform.php

To a user this seems fine but the server thinks that the **www.** version of the site is a different website and doesn't grab your variables.

For consistency you should always force a user to either the **www.** or **non www.** version of your website using a **.htaccess** file.

Hope that helps.